# How to create custom user profile using Django 1.5?

Tags: python, django

How to create new custom user profile using Django 1.5? The documentation is not clear to me

For example I need:

```
class StandardProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and

```
class ArtistProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255) #or ForeignKey(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    music = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How to change this to new user custom model?

(I want to use to authenticate users this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use django 1.5's [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), because you can only have such one model.

In your case, you're probably looking to have a [OneToOne relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) between each of your `Profiles` and the `User` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StandardProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ArtistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    music = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could use: AbstractBaseUser or something like this.

Comment: @usermoon That's not needed in your case!